# How can I define a multiprocessing.pool as a class member?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

For some reason,I can't just paste my codes here,My codes are just like below:

```
import multiprocessing as mt


def dosomething(text=""):
    print text


class A:
    pool = mt.Pool(mt.cpu_count())

    def someting(self):
        for i in range(mt.cpu_count()):
            self.pool.apply_async(dosomething, args=('1234',))
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()
```

And I call this method in another file:

```
from test2 import A

if __name__ == "__main__":
    realA = A()
    print realA.pool
    realA.someting()
```

When I run it, the console keeps showing like these:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 510, in prepare
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled\test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 510, in prepare
    from test2 import A
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled\test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    class A:
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled\test2.py", line 9, in A
    pool = mt.Pool(mt.cpu_count())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 161, in __init__
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled\test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test2 import A
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 225, in _repopulate_pool
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled\test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    class A:
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled\test2.py", line 9, in A
    pool = mt.Pool(mt.cpu_count())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    w.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 161, in __init__
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 258, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 225, in _repopulate_pool
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 358, in get_command_line
    w.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 510, in prepare
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 258, in __init__
    is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
                    ...

            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
```

But When I write the multiprocessing.pool in method,this problem just gone,Why? This problem disturbs for a long time, I use the multiprocessing for performance improve,but this problem makes me can't continue.Because if I do these things in a class method,the codes will continue producing a lot of sub processings and makes the Windows break up,a single Pool object can help manage the processing. Anyway,thanks